# sqlplus / as sysdba is not working in windows, ERROR: ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, sqlplus

I tried to login using `sqlplus / as sysdba` in Oracle 11g, but it is asking for a password. So I tried to login using `sqlplus "/ as sysdba"` since I'm using Windows. But it is showing the following error:

```
sqlplus "/ as sysdba"

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Mon May 22 12:51:22 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:

ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
```

I googled this same issue,But nothing could help me out.

Comment: Is the oracle service actually running?

Comment: Actually I'm trying to configure Data Guard... For that I have to configure Standby database. In standby db, only oracle software should be installed.  So I haven't created database in it.. I have installed only oracle software. Because of that there is no Oracle Service with my db name in Services.msc. Now I have to login as sqlplus / as sysdba to do further configurations...

Comment: @JoeJoyValiyaveettil No, you still have to create the database using DBCA (which creates the Oracle Windows services) before you can connect to it (even as sysdba to an idle instance).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like database is not up. It might be due to restarting machine and the

```
1. Go to the windows machine that hosts the Oracle database server
2. Go to Start -> Run -> Services.msc in windows. Locate OracleService (here OracleServiceORCL) and click on "Start" to start the oracle database service (if not already running)

3. Once it is up and running, from the command prompt run the following:

   tnsping < tnsalias >

   (tnsalias entry you can find it in tnsnames.ora file)
```

Comment: Actually I'm trying to configure Data Guard... For that I have to configure Standby database. In standby db, only oracle software should be installed.  So I haven't created database in it.. I have installed only oracle software. Because of that there is no Oracle Service with my db name in Services.msc. Now I have to login as sqlplus / as sysdba to do further configurations...

Comment: To get DataGuard going, you have to clone the existing database, for which you need the Standby instance in a "sort of running" state.  Create a pfile with the right database name and start that, then create the Standby database from [a backup of] the Primary, which will create everything else.